# Generic method call confusion

Tags: java, generics, dynamic

I have created a function

```
public <T> void someFunction(T object) {
    object.someMethod();
}
```

I have two classes which has same **someMethod()** function definition. I have to invoke the function by passing argument, the object of these two classes depends on the input provided.

Comment: What is the question; what problem are you having?

Comment: I have to invoke function of two classes depending on the input value provided .One class is built in and other is user defined one

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since `T` has no type bounds, the compiler can't know if that parameter would be replaced by a class that has a `someMethod` method.

You can add a type bound:

```
public <T extends HasSomeMethod> void someFunction(T object) {
    object.someMethod();
}
```

Where `HasSomeMethod` is an interface that contains the `someMethod` method, and the two classes that have `someMethod` implement that interface. (it will also work if `HasSomeMethod` is a super-class of your two classes, and it contains the `someMethod` method (either abstract or not).

EDIT :

An example of wrapping PreparedStatement :

```
public class MyStatement implements HasSomeMethod
{
    PreparedStatement stmt;

    public MyStatement (PreparedStatement stmt) {
         this.stmt = stmt;
    }

    public void someMethod ()
    {
        stmt.someMethod ();
    }
}
```

Now if you have a `PreparedStatement` instance, you can write :

```
PreparedStatement ps = ...
MyStatement my = new MyStatement(ps);
```

and pass `my` to your `someFunction` method.

Comment: one object is of a java library class and another of user defined class. So the first class is a compiled code. So how can we implement same interface for these two classes

Comment: @AkhilSudhakaran Perhaps you can wrap the library class with a second user defined class that implements the interface.

Comment: can you explain in detail. I am just a beginner. With example PreparedStatement as built in class and MyStatement as user defined class

Comment: It might also be worth mentioning that generics is unnecessary here. `pubic void someFunction(HasSomeMethod object)` is equivalent